# Google map div within an element not working

Tags: html, css

I am using a google map and have it structured in side an element like this.

```
<main id="panel" class="panel">
   <div class="topBar"></div>  
   <div id="map"></div>
</main>
```

Now if i remove the element main the map displays perfectly, but as soon as i add the element it disapears.

This is the CSS

```
#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I have tried to re write the css thinking that the structure of the css is the problem, but whatever i try doesn't work. for example

```
main map {}
```

[Here Is A  Link](http://1711.co.uk/proximity.html)

Comment: Can you share a working code example? This isn't enough information to really look at what's going on.

Comment: Did you set a height to topBar? the map is "100%" height of it's parent, if topBar has no height then 100% of 0 is 0

Comment: I have added a link, Yes i changed the height to reflect the top bar and I even removed the top bar and footer but nothing changes unless i remove the main element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `height: 100%;` on the `main.panel` element.

**Explanation:**

Your `#map` element is set to `height: 100%` which means it will take up completely (100%) the height of its parent element, `<main>` in this case.

Since there was only a `min-height` property and no `height` property on the `<main>`, the `#map` had no `height` to inherit, hence it took 0 `height`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained how percentage heights work (i.e. how they determine their height).